# Are there prime-mimicking functions?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am seeking a function $q(n)$ with these three properties:

1. $q(n) \approx p(n)$, where $p(n)$ is the $n$-th prime number.
2. $q(n)$ can be expressed "using a finite number of standard operations,"
   i.e., it can be expressed in
   "[closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression)."
3. $q(n)$ has the same asymptotic distribution as the primes, $p(n)$: the number of $q(x)$
   less than or equal to $N$ is asymptotically $N / \log N$.

These properties are not sharply defined, but perhaps this will clarify my intent.
Define $q(n)$ as
$$
q(n) = \textrm{round} \left[ \; n \, (\, \log (n)+\log (\log (n))-1\,) \; \right] \;.
$$
This is an approximation to $p(n)$;
see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities).
For example, $p(47) = 211$ and $q(47) = 197$.
So $q(n)$ satisfies conditions (1) and (2).
Whether it also satisfies (3) is unclear (to me).

There is some latitude in interpreting the $\approx$ in (1),
the "standard operations" in (2), and
"the same asymptotic distribution" in (3).
Nevertheless, I expect this is well-covered ground,
and experts can point me in the right direction.
Likely there are many $q(n)$ that can meet the three criteria.

Comment: The counting function being asymptotically $N/\log N$ is equivalent to $q(n) \sim n\log n$. Thus your $q$ works, and everything that works isn't too different from it.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! This pretty much answers my question.